# Winterbash: Some hats cannot been obtained

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2018

I don't like that there are a lot of hats which I cannot get since I'm not a fresh user or that I already own the Guru badge. Also the Team hat seems to be only obtainable if you are part of a paid Team. Pay to win. Great! That makes no fun.

Answer (score 9):

- You can earn the Still Fresh hat on another site in the network you haven't joined yet (and wear it on Stack Overflow if you like). FWIW, [I can't](https://stackexchange.com/users/6085540/glorfindel?tab=accounts).
- You can earn the Guru badge multiple times, so it doesn't matter that you've already earned it; if you earn another Guru badge, you'll get the hat.
- You earn the Team Player hat by just visiting the [Teams page](https://stackoverflow.com/teams), you don't need to be part of a Team. There might be a delay on that hat, because the data is coming from a different system.

Comment: I don't want to sign up on a site just for a hat. It is also not helpful to have a non active user out of my opinion. The guru badge is a lot of work and is still just awarded on that special site. The link does not work for getting the hat! I tied it hours ago.

Comment: @rekire if you don't want to play, no hats for you. FWIW I've also trouble in getting that teams hat on both my main and sock-puppet account. So either it is caching or broken ...

Comment: If you don't want to sign up on a site for a hat the simple solution is to simply not sign up on a site for a hat.

Comment: Regarding: _FWIW, I can't:_ o.O

Comment: What a surprise I got the team hat now

Comment: What a surprise I got the team hat now. @rekire

Comment: @honk He should definitely get a hat for that.