# Winter Bash Team Player hat not awarded

Tags: support, winter-bash-2018

I just discovered that after visiting the [SO Teams landing-page](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) no hat was awarded. Am I missing something?

[image]

Is there a certain delay to it?

Comment: How long ago did you visit it? It took a while for me to receive the hat.

Comment: @Codeer multiple times, the first time about 30 mins ago ..

Comment: As always, be patient. For me it took a few hours...

Comment: The answer on this question mentions there is a possible delay on the teams hat: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377737/winterbash-some-hats-cannot-been-obtained I'm sure it will arrive to you in 6-8 weeks at most ;)

Comment: @honk patients is virtue which is as far away to me as parsing html with regex ;)

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex is easy. It just has some [side effects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2675154) ;)

Comment: @honk One of the best.. ;)

Comment: seems like a bug.. What i don't understand are the downvotes since you report something thats not working as it supposed to..

Comment: @CHINAMAN Maybe they disagree or are not experiencing the same issue - meta rep is just a indicator of approval/disapproval - The downvotes don't really matter to me ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will get it in few hours later. I had the same issue - I had opened a lot of times the SO Teams landing-page and I had thought that it is a bug or something like that. But few hours later I got this hat.

My suggestion for SO developers: please write for this hat something like follows:

> "Don't worry! You will get this hat in few hours later."

Comment: @Codeer What will I wear then when I leave the office in 2 hours, it's quite cold and windy out there.. ;)

Comment: @iLuvLogix, sometimes the cool head is better than warm hat! ;-)

Comment: A cool beer is even better ;)

Comment: I think we should write it under every hat :)

Comment: It's a test....to see if the user is wise enough to check meta for an answer before posting another Teams Hat question....:)  Maybe there should be another hat for that?

Comment: Response time may be server load dependent. I received my Teams hat about 30-45 minutes after visiting the Teams site.